# What was the ₧ symbol used for?

Tags: ascii

In ASCII, symbol 158 is ₧.

What does this symbol stand for, and what was it used for?

Comment: 158 is multiplication (x) http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/multiplication-sign-ascii-code-158.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASCII only goes up to 126, so your question doesn't make sense. However, the symbol "₧" stands for [Spanish pesetas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_peseta), and is part of the old codepage 437. Nowadays it's part of Unicode as [U+20A7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a7/index.htm).

Comment: No, PTS stands for points. ₧ is the exact same as PTS.